# How to snag a bmp for screen shot in .net where whole form doesn't totally fit on screen?

Tags: vb.net

I am coding a form that has veritical scrollbar because the height of the form is larger then the display are of screen. I am trying to create a printscreen to print the entire form. However all I have been able to do is capture only the section of form that is visible at the time the capture to .bmp
Does anyone know of a way where I can capture the entire form even the part that would need to be scrolled to view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I take a screenshot of a Winforms control/form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493591/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-winforms-control-form-in-c)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309095/14171304